# Laravel のEloquent モデルについて

Tags: php, laravel

Eloquentに関して初歩的な質問をさせてください。
get()で BelongTo 先のテーブルのデータを取得することができませんでした。

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Item extends Model
{
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

```
 $item = Item::where('id', 1)->get();
```

としたところ関連付けしてあるユーザの情報を取ることができませんでした。

```
 $item = Item::where('id', 1)->first();
```

とすることで、ユーザテーブルがJoinされ、ユーザ情報の取得ができました。

getでは、Modelに該当しているテーブルのみからしかデータを取得できないのでしょうか？

Comment: Laravelのeager loadingではjoinを使用せずにリレーションを取得するはずですし、実行されるクエリはほぼ同じはずですが、何をもって「ユーザテーブルがJoinされ、ユーザ情報の取得ができました。」と判断されたのでしょうか。なお、実際に呼ばれているクエリはクエリログを取ってみてみるといいかもしれません……

Answer (score 0):

Eloquentにjoinという概念は無いです。

belongTo()のようなリレーションシップを作った場合の挙動は、通常Lazy Loadingとなり、今回の例では以下のようにしてusersテーブルのデータを取得します。

```
$item = Item::where('id', 1)->get();
echo $item[0]->user->name;

//itemに紐付いたuserの名前を表示
```

この際、Eloquentでは以下のようなSQLを実行します。

```
select * from items where id = 1;
select * from users where id = {items.user_id};
```

またテックブログや解説書で推奨されるwithを使った方法(Eager Loading)では以下となります。

```
$item = Item::with('users')->where('id', 1)->get();
echo $item[0]->user->name;

//itemに紐付いたuserの名前を表示
```

この際、Eloquentでは以下のようなSQLを実行します。

```
select * from items where id = 1;
select * from users where id in ({items.user_id});
```

そして今回勘違いされているfirstを使った場合は以下となります。

```
$item = Item::where('id', 1)->first();
echo $item->user->name;

//itemに紐付いたuserの名前を表示
```

```
select * from items where id = 1 limit 1;
select * from users where id = {items.user_id};
```

違いは、get()は複数件返ることを前提に、各userのコレクションを配列に格納して返すのに対して、first()は、1件しか返らない前提なので、コレクションそのものが返ってきます。おそらくあなたは、get()のときも、$item->user->name として値が取り出せると期待していたのでしょうが、そうならず、fist(）では、$item->user->name で取り出せたので、joinされた！と勘違いしているのではないでしょうか。